# Is it possible to use a typeclass to implement a trait?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, subtyping

I have a situation where I'd like to implement a given trait (`CanBeString` in the example below). I would like to have the option either to implement that trait using a newly created case class (`NewImplementation` in the example below), or to implement it by adding functionality to some pre-existing type (just `Int` in the example below), by using a type class. This is probably best illustrated by the below:

```
package example

// typeclass
trait ConvertsToString[A] {
  def asString(value: A): String
}

// the trait I would like the typeclass to implement
trait CanBeString {
  def asString: String
}

// this implementation approach taken from the scala with cats book
object ConvertsToStringInstances {
  implicit val intConvertsToString: ConvertsToString[Int] = 
    new ConvertsToString[Int] {
      def asString(value: Int): String = s"${value}"
    }
}

object ConvertsToStringSyntax {
  implicit class ConvertsToStringOps[A](value: A) {
    def asString(implicit c: ConvertsToString[A]): String = c.asString(value)
  }
}

object Test {
  import ConvertsToStringInstances._
  import ConvertsToStringSyntax._

  def testAsFunc(c: CanBeString): String = c.asString

  case class NewImplementation (f: Double) extends CanBeString {
    def asString = s"{f}"
  }

  println(testAsFunc(NewImplementation(1.002))) // this works fine!
  println(testAsFunc(1)) // this sadly does not.
}
```

Is anything like this possible? I'm only recently discovering the topic of typeclasses so I'm aware that what I'm asking for here may be possible but just unwise - if so please chime in and let me know what a better idiom might be.

Thanks in advance, and also afterwards!

Comment: If you control the original trait and all the types that already extend it, the best would be to just make it a typeclass from the beginning.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - thanks - I understand what you mean and this is a useful pointer. I have looked at my code again and I'm going to be using the same type parameter for the typeclass throughout my code, so I think the sensible thing is to use a typeclass but then to make a concrete trait from it by passing it this type parameter, and use this throughout the code.

Comment: Uhm, well it doesn't sound like a bad design, but it is quite unusual. I would just keep asking for the **typeclass** all the way down. In this case, it seems that you really have is a **magnet pattern** rather than a **typeclass** _(well, actually like a mix of both where the **magnet** transformation is not done implicitly but through the **typeclass**, which I kind of like)_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example you can have two overloaded versions of `testAsFunc` (OOP-style and typeclass-style)

```
object Test {
  ...

  def testAsFunc(c: CanBeString): String = c.asString
  def testAsFunc[C: ConvertsToString](c: C): String = c.asString

  println(testAsFunc(NewImplementation(1.002))) // {f}
  println(testAsFunc(1)) // 1
}
```

Or if you prefer to have the only `testAsFunc` then you can add instances of the type class for subtypes of the trait to be implemented

```
object ConvertsToStringInstances {
  implicit val intConvertsToString: ConvertsToString[Int] = ...

  implicit def canBeStringSubtypeConvertsToString[A <: CanBeString]: ConvertsToString[A] =
    new ConvertsToString[A] {
      override def asString(value: A): String = value.asString
    }
}

object Test {
  ...

  def testAsFunc[C: ConvertsToString](c: C): String = c.asString

  println(testAsFunc(NewImplementation(1.002))) // {f}
  println(testAsFunc(1)) // 1
}
```

Please notice that if for a `c` there are both OOP-ish `c.asString` and extension-method `c.asString` then only the first is actually called.